# ¿Porque me aparece un scroll cuando posiciono los elementos con CSS?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un scroll cuando posiciono mis dos circulos **ESTOY TRABAJANDO EN MOBILE FIRST POR LO QUE EN ESCRITORIO NO FUNCIONA AUN**, el primero funciona bien y no hay scroll, pero al posicionar el segundo circulo me sale un scroll lateral e inferior, adjunto mi codigo. He intentado cambiando las posiciones de absolute y relative pero simplemente no consigo hacerlo, intente con z-index pero igual no me funciona, ayuda por favor. El circulo azul debe estar en la esquina superior derecha y el circulo rosado en la esquina inferior derecha.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html {
   font-size: 62.5%;
}

.background {
   background-color: #101010;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10000;
}

.circle--blue {
   background: radial-gradient(81.25% 81.25% at 67.32% 18.75%, #17B3A9 0%, #0945DF 100%);
   border-radius: 100%;
   height: 30rem;
   transform: rotate(245deg);
   width: 30rem;
   position: absolute;
   left: -15%;
   top: -10%;
   z-index: 1;

}

.circle--red {
   background: radial-gradient(76.75% 76.75% at 70% 23.25%, #7717B3 0%, #DF09CA 100%);
   height: 20rem;
   width: 20rem;
   border-radius: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -10%;
   right: -10%;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>

   <div class="background">
      <div class="circle--blue"></div>
      <div class="circle--red"></div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @BetaM No del todo ya que segun mi ejemplo mi contenedor padre es relativo y los hijos son absolutos por lo que se supone no debe existir scroll pero aun asi sigue saliendo :(

Comment: si no deseas scrollers debes usar el atrtibuto overflow asignando hidden en el estilo del contenedor. **Pero** eso no resuelve el tema de las dimensiones (si necesitas mostrar los círculos completos, cosa a la que no haces referencia). `selector { overflow: hidden; }` el default es auto muestra los scrollers.

Comment: @quevedo No, los circulos tienen ese aspecto de estar cortados en la version movil, la cual la hago desde mobile first, y si ocupo overflow:hidden el contenido se me mueve nuevamente, obviamente quita el scroll pero quisiera saber si hay alguna solucion que me los mantenga tal cual

Comment: @quevedo permíteme agradecerte, al parecer funcionó, si puedes escribir tu respuesta para poderte dar la respuesta correcta, adjúntala por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ocultar el contenido que desborda un contenedor, **de modo que no muestre los scrollers** se puede utilizar el atributo **overflow** del mismo asignando su valor a **hidden**.

La atribución del estilo se hace mediante la sintaxis:

```
    selector { overflow: hidden; }
```

En tu caso se puede aprovechar la clase asignada al contenedor de fondo para que no afecte a otros elementos que puedan estar presentes en la página, así:

```
    .background { overflow: hidden; }
```

referencia: [Overflow (excedente)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Gracias compa me ayudó mucho

Comment: Para eso estamos. Hay veces en que los árboles ocultan el bosque.